# AngularJS binding in 'src' attribute of <img> tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image, browser

I have a `table` with many `rows` and each row has a preview image to be shown on the top right corner when mouse is hovering the row.

This is how I put the image tag with AngularJS binding for URL in `src` attribute:

```
<img src="{{imageUrl}}"/>
```

But there is the following error in console:

> GET http://localhost/#/imageUrl **404 (Not Found)**

How to get rid of this error in browser console?

Comment: Use `ng-src` instead of `src`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Angular has its own directive for `img`, called [**`ng-src`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc):

```
<img ng-src="{{imageUrl}}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `ng-src` instead of `src` in your `<img>` tag.

The documentation says like this,

*Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.*

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Hope this helps!